# Calculating probability for rolling dice

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Probability that i don't get $6$ while throwing a die $10$ times. I used binomial distribution: $ {N \choose k} (p^m (1-p)^{n-m})$ Is it right to solve this with this formula? ${10 \choose0} (\frac 1 6)^0 (1 - \frac 1 6)^{10} = 0.15$?

Comment: Don't round prematurely! $(5/6)^{10} \approx 0.1615$

Answer (score 2):

Correct formula, with incorrect rounding. I make this 0.162.

Comment: Since we're being pedantic about the rounding, the real answer is closer to $0.1615056$

Comment: @Khan I doubt your explanation -- but if you do actually have a calculator that thinks $(5/6)^{10} = 0.15$ it's broken. You might be able to use it for a paperweight or something but don't use it for calculating.